# ASP.NET MVC3: How do I hide fields using Html.DisplayForModel and Html.EditorForModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using the following two methods in my view and edit views, They run off the model and automatically generate a list of the fields with labels, to display/edit.

```
  @Html.EditorForModel()

  @Html.DisplayForModel()
```

The problem is that they display every field.. Including the ID field, which is bad when it comes to editing as it should not be changed.

So, How do I hide certain fields in the model. (without removing the fields from the model.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `Scaffold` Attribute

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

And if you also want that the model binder does not touch the Id field (to prevent over-posting) you can set the `ReadOnly`-Attribute too.

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Even via my .net library. Cheers.